# Aspose.Word - Unable to add more than 10 rows to an existing table from template

Tags: aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

With the below code, I'm able to add 10 rows at the max. When i try to add more rows, Aspose is throwing an exception.

```
Try
    Dim doc As Document = New Document("C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Junk\Out.doc")
    Dim table As Table = DirectCast(doc.GetChild(NodeType.Table, 0, True), Table)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim clonedRow As Row = DirectCast(table.LastRow.Clone(True), Row)
        For Each cell As Cell In clonedRow.Cells
            cell.CellFormat.Orientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal
            cell.CellFormat.WrapText = True
            cell.CellFormat.FitText = True
            cell.FirstParagraph.Runs.Clear()
            cell.FirstParagraph.AppendChild(New Aspose.Words.Run(doc, "hellotext"))
        Next
        ' Add the row to the end of the table.
        table.AppendChild(clonedRow)
    Next

    doc.Save("C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Junk\Out1.pdf")

Catch x As Exception
    Dim y As String = ""
End Try
```

Exception:
[[image: Exception[1]]

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at    .(    , Int32 , Boolean )
   at    .(ArrayList , Boolean )
   at    .(ArrayList , Int32 )
   at    .(ArrayList ,    , Int32 , Boolean , Boolean )
   at    . (Table )
   at    .(Table , Boolean )
   at    .(Table , Stack , Boolean )
   at    .VisitTableEnd(Table )
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptChildren(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at Aspose.Words.CompositeNode.AcceptCore(DocumentVisitor visitor)
   at    .(    )
   at    .(Document , ​   )
   at    .(    ,     )
   at    .      (    )
   at    .      (    )
   at Aspose.Words.Document.(Stream , String , SaveOptions )
   at Aspose.Words.Document.Save(String fileName)
   at WindowsApplication1.IMPlanSetupTest.newpdfgen() in C:\Projects\BFL\Source\BFL.WindowsApplication1\IMPlanSetupTest.vb:line 63
```

I'm kind of struck with this piece here. When i change `For i As Integer = 0 To 10` to any number less than 10, It is working.

Comment: This question is also posted here https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/833824/unable-to-add-more-than-10-rows-to-an-existing-table-from-template/showthread.aspx#833824

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end for 10+ rows. Please share your source document to replicate the issue.

Comment: I just tested with other examples and have the same issue.
Best way to reproduce this issue is by creating a work document with a table of size 5(Rows)x1(Column) and try adding 99 rows using above code. It is failing with the same exception as above.

Comment: You are getting issue due to evaluation version. Please note the evaluation version of Aspose.Words (without a license specified) provides full product functionality, but it inserts an evaluation watermark at the top of the document on open and save, and limits the maximum document size to several hundred paragraphs. Please make a request for [30 days temporary license](http://www.aspose.com/corporate/purchase/temporary-license.aspx) and apply it, it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tilal mentioned above, this limitation is due to evaluation version of aspose. After applying proper license, i'm able to insert 10+ rows into the document.

Cheers.